# Memory Leak from NSMutableArray and NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have a memomry leak problem, maybe somebody can help me.
I try to load an NSMutable array for a pList and show some elements in a TablevView

In the h.File I declare

```
@interface Bestellung : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisen;
NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenPreis;
NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenDetails;
NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenBild;
NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenNummer;

NSMutableArray *bestellListe;


IBOutlet UITableView *myTable; 


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bestellListe;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisen;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenPreis;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenDetails;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenBild;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *bestellteVorspeisenNummer;

@end
```

In the M.File viewDidLoad I load the pList in bestellListe

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bestellung.plist"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (!success) 
{       
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bestellung" ofType:@"plist"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:&error];
    }   
    self.bestellListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Then I generate the MutableArray

```
bestellteVorspeisen     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenPreis        = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenDetails  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenBild     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenNummer   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

Afterwards I fill them from bestellListe

```
for (NSDictionary *bestellDict in bestellListe) 
    {   if ([[bestellDict objectForKey:@"Tisch"] isEqualToString: 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",TischNummer]]) 
        {if ([[bestellDict objectForKey: kBestellungKategorieString] isEqualToString: @"Vorspeise"])  
            [bestellteVorspeisen            addObject: [bestellDict objectForKey:kBestellungNameString]]; 
                [bestellteVorspeisenPreis       addObject: [bestellDict objectForKey:kBestellungPreisString]]; 
                [bestellteVorspeisenDetails     addObject: [bestellDict objectForKey:kBestellungDetailString]]; 
                [bestellteVorspeisenBild        addObject: [bestellDict objectForKey:kBestellungBildString]];
                [bestellteVorspeisenNummer      addObject: [bestellDict objectForKey:kBestellungNummer]];
} // if
} // if
} // for
```

This causes memoryleaks at

```
self.bestellListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

and

```
bestellteVorspeisen     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenPreis        = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenDetails  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenBild     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; 
bestellteVorspeisenNummer   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

Here ist dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {

NSLog(@"Bestellung dealloziert");

[bestellteVorspeisen            release];
[bestellteVorspeisenPreis       release];
[bestellteVorspeisenDetails     release];
[bestellteVorspeisenBild        release];
[bestellteVorspeisenNummer      release];

[bestellListe                   release];
[myTable                        release];

[super dealloc];
```

Can somebody give me some help, I'm really new in that.

Comment: can you edit and put all the code in formatted codeblocks, bitte.

Answer (score 5):

your property synthesized method automatically retains received objects :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bestellListe;
```

So when you do :

```
self.bestellListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Your bestellListe has a retain count of 2 (the alloc + the retain from the property).

On your dealloc you only release it once :

```
[bestellListe release];
```

The simpler solution seems to retain it only once when creating it, with an autoreleased initializer like :

```
self.bestellListe = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Hope this can help